# Run Script At Shutdown but not Reboot (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, script

I'd like to run a script to turn off my monitor when my PC is shutdown, but only when properly shutting down and not rebooting. Obviously if I'm rebooting, I want the screen to stay on!

I know you can run scripts at shutdown via GPO, but I don't know how I'd filter out restarts and would appreciate some help on ways to achieve this. I'm pretty flexible - all I have to do is send an HTTP request out on my network, so I'm not stuck with any type of scripting in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows logs the shutdown or restart into event log. The id of the event is 1074.
With the event it is logged, if it is a shutdown or restart.
Your shutdown script has to read this event. With powershell:

```
# Check shutdown event if Shutdown or Restart is active
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='System'; id=1074} -MaxEvents 1 | ForEach-Object {
     $command = $_.Properties[4].Value
    }
```

$command is the searched information. Please note that the value is language dependent.

Comment: Worked great for me - for a restart $command was equal to "restart" and for a shutdown it was "power off". This was using powershell.